# SELECT * FROM TABLE, TABLE depending on another query - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Here's what I'm trying to achieve :
Select a person's or firm's name depending on the contact type.

Tables :

```
CONTACTS :               PEOPLE              FIRMS
- id                     - contact_id        - contact_id    
- type (person/firm)     - name              - name
```

I would like this kind of magic :

```
SELECT type 
FROM contacts 
WHERE contacts.id = 42;

SELECT model.name 
FROM contacts LEFT JOIN model ON model.contact_id = contacts.id 
WHERE contacts_id = 42 
AND model = CASE (WHEN type = "person" THEN "people" 
                  WHEN type = "firm" THEN "Firms" END); (Not sure this one works)
```

All in one query. Thanks !

Comment: Whats wrong with it? Please provide some sample data and sample output.

Comment: What's `model`? You said you have 3 tables and then you use some other in your SQL.

Comment: Haha, *model* confused me, too. It's supposed to be some kind of variable being replaced with either table people or firms depending on the type. Sometimes it's hard to read pseudo code :-)

Comment: @user2688870: It would be nice, after posting a request to react on the comments. You notice you got almost immediate reactions from people wanting to help, but you didn't answer their questions.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry but I have a lot a work to do and I can't stay tuned on SO all day long. By the way thanks for the help guys, Model was indeed a variable or alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply left join both tables; one of them will match id and type. Use COALESCE then to display the one name found.

```
select coalesce(p.name, f.name) as name
from contacts c
left join people p on p.contacts_id = c.id and c.type = 'person'
left join firms f on f.contacts_id = c.id and c.type = 'firm'
where c.id = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like below, join two tables and then decide which column to use according to `contacts.type`.

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN t1.type = 'person' THEN t2.name WHEN t1.type = 'firm' THEN t3.name) AS contact_name
FROM contacts t1
LEFT JOIN people t2 ON t1.id = t2.contact_id
LEFT JOIN firms t3 ON t1.id = t3.contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql like this:

```
declare 
    @table_name nvarchar(20),
    @query nvarchar(max)

SELECT 
    @table_name = 
                    case type 
                        when 'person' then 'people'
                        when 'firm' then 'firms'
                    end
FROM contacts  
WHERE contacts.id = 42;


set @query = N'SELECT ' + @table_name + '.name ' +
                'FROM contacts LEFT JOIN model ON ' + @table_name + '.contact_id = contacts.id 
                WHERE contacts_id = 42 '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way without a join:

```
select 
  case when c.type = 'person' then
    (select name from people p where p.contacts_id = c.id)
  else
    (select name from firms f on f.contacts_id = c.id)
  end as name
from contacts c
where c.id = 42;
```

You see, there are many ways to address the problem. Just pick the one you find most readable.

Comment: Don't always go for most readable. You should take into account performance. You can do that by looking at the explain plan of the 2 and comparing them.

Comment: I usually go for readability first. I do care about performance optimization when performance issues occur. Which is not likely to happen when looking up a single record by id :-)